# How to deal with a highly imbalanced Issue(Text) classification Dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

Size of the dataset: 81256,
Classes:200,
Range for each class varies from 2757 under a particular class to as low as 10 under particular class.Its highly unbalanced.
How to balance this dataset and what type of algorithm should be used to train the model.
Right now i have used random over sampler for sampling and Linear SVC to train the model.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not about general programming advice and recommendations; your question is way too broad (as is the issue of class imbalance itself), please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general question, but some methods to deal with unbalanced data in text (and not only) are:

- Collect more data
- Oversample minority classes
- Undersample majority classes
- Augumentation through back-translation: use some translation API (Google Translate) and translate your text into another language, and then translate the translated text back to original language
- Augumentation through synonyms: replace some of the words in your text with their synonyms
- Use pretrained models (BERT, GTP-2) that do not require much data for fine-tuning